# How to update and switch branch with a checkout when using pipenv?

Tags: pipenv

I'm using `pipenv` and have a repository checked out: `https://github.com/rvanlaar/django-tinymce4-lite` with branch `rvanlaar-patch-1`.

I want to switch this checkout to `master`. How can I do that?

I tried changing the Pipfile and running `pipenv sync`.

Comment: I even don't understand what do You want  to do ? `pipenv` is package/env manager while `git` is repository manager. SO if U want to checkout `master` You must use `git checkout master`. What `pipenv` have there to do ?

Comment: To use this pipenv feature: https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#a-note-about-vcs-dependencies

Comment: You can specify the branch with the `ref` property of the dependency object. Like this `{git = "https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller", ref = "develop"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pipenv install` updated the git checkout.